# How to check the number of BTC sent from one address to another via API?

Tags: blockchain.info, api

I need to count the number of sent coins from an address to another address.

I found this API https://blockchain.info/rawaddr, is it enough for me, using this method, to simply calculate the "outputs" of the transaction to the address?

JS Code example:

```
const valueAddreses: IValueAddress = {};

axios.get(`https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/${address}`)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.data.txs?.length) {
      res.data.txs.forEach((tx) => {
        tx.out.forEach((out) => {
          if (out.value > 0 && out.addr === findAddress) {
            if (!valueAddreses[out.addr]) {
              valueAddreses[out.addr] = {value: out.value};
            }

            valueAddreses[out.addr].value += out.value;
            valueAddreses[out.addr].valid = valueAddreses[out.addr].value >= minLimitSat;
          }
        })
      });

      res.json(valueAddreses);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Does JavaScript support back ticks?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: What have you tried? Why don't you trust this code block?